# Uninstall + Re-Install from terminal errors

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, software-installation, printing

I'm a beginner in working with Ubuntu. I have a Windows 7 32-bit installation and Ubuntu 14.04 installation (dual-boot.) I've installed `UnifidLinuxDriver-1.00.27.tar.gz` and `Smartpanel_0.98.tar.gz` for my **Samsung ML1865w printer**. After printing some pages, an error message was displayed that said that the Smartpanel software crashed. Now I want to uninstall that program and re-install it, but I can't locate the program or its dependancy packages.

I downloaded `UnifiedLinuxDriver-1.00.27.tar.gz` from [bchemnet](http://bchemnet.com/) and extracted the files to a folder on the desktop. 
I then opened a terminal window and entered these commands that I copied and pasted:

```
giri@giri-desktop:~$ sudo bash -c 'echo "deb http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/ debian extra" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
giri@giri-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get update
giri@giri-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install suld-driver-4.01.17
```

Throughout the process of these commands, I agreed with all of the `y or n` prompts.

Then I installed the Samsung SmartPanel with the following commands:

```
giri@giri-desktop:~/Desktop/cdroot/Linux/smartpanel$ sudo ./install.sh . 
libstdc++.so.5 (gcc 3.0.x .. 3.3.x) not found, intstall ... done 
INFO: Shutting down smartpanel: 
INFO: smartpanel (ver.2.00.65) has been installed successfully in /opt/Samsung/SmartPanel 
INFO: Starting smartpanel ... 
giri@giri-desktop:~/Desktop/cdroot/Linux/smartpanel$
```

How can I uninstall this program?

Answer (score 0):

You can check wether the package is installed with the following command:

```
dpkg -l suld-driver-4.01.17
```

And to show where its files are installed enter:

```
dpkg -S suld-driver-4.01.17
```

At least parts of SmartPanel are installed in /opt/Samsung/. You'd have to check the install.sh to be sure, but you might try to move that folder and reinstall.

Comment: Sir, I have typed the command: dpkg -l suld-driver-4.01.17 and the result is:- giri@giri-desktop:~$ dpkg -l suld-driver-4.01.17
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  suld-driver-4. 4.01.17-4    i386         Samsung Unified Linux Driver
giri@giri-desktop:~$

Comment: Sir, You asked me to  'check the install.sh to be sure, and try to move that folder and reinstall.' Will you please explain how can I remove and reinstall these  programmes ?.

Comment: This line tells you that the package in query is actually installed:

Comment: `ii suld-driver-4. 4.01.17-4 i386 Samsung Unified Linux Driver`

Comment: This line tells you that the package in query is actually installed:
`ii suld-driver-4. 4.01.17-4 i386 Samsung Unified Linux Driver`
Now you can uninstall that package with:
`dpkg -r --purge suld-driver-4.01.17`

Comment: Sir, You asked me to 'check the install.sh to be sure, and try to move that folder and reinstall'.  Will you please explain how can I remove the  install.sh folder of  Smart-panel.